# How do I get the tag of a button from an inflated Android table?

Tags: android, android-layout

How do I get the tag of a button from an inflated table?  I have the following code so far, now how do I get the tag from a button when I press a button?

```
TableLayout table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.scheduleTable);
for (int i = 0; i < jlen; i++) { 

    // Inflate
    TableRow row = (TableRow)LayoutInflater.from(UpdateScheduleActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.schedulerow, null);
    ((TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.attr_day)).setText(json_schedule.getString(KEY_DOW));
    ((TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.attr_start)).setText(json_schedule.getString(KEY_START));
    ((TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.attr_stop)).setText(json_schedule.getString(KEY_STOP));
    ((Button)row.findViewById(R.id.btnRemove)).setTag(sid);
    table.addView(row);

}
table.requestLayout();
```

Answer (score 1):

in your case

```
btn = (Button)**row**.findViewById(R.id.btnRemove);
```

hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

You should get a reference to the button in your onItemClick or onClickListener, from there just use view.getTag()

Answer (score 0):

As ByteMe said, you need to set onClickListener for your button. Something like that may work:

```
((Button)row.findViewById(R.id.btnRemove)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ((Button) v).getTag();
        // Do whatever you like when the button is pressed.
    }
 });
```